# Can we log both access & content changes?

Tags: security, authentication

If we implement CraftCMS, we would need logging of both access and publishing (both successful and failed attempts). The ability to change/remove those logs should not be available to those using the CMS. Is this available in core?

Answer (score 3):

Craft does some basic logging in the form of when an entry was updated/created and the last time a user logged in and from what IP address, etc.  If you want anything more detailed than that, you'd need a plugin.  There is one called [Audit Log](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/auditlog) that might do what you're looking for.